# Error when modifying a primary key as a foreign key

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have a primary key as a foreign key in Entity Framework.

```
public class RailcarTrip
{
    [Key, ForeignKey("WaybillRailcar")]
    public int WaybillRailcarId { get; set; }
    public WaybillRailcar WaybillRailcar { get; set; }

    // Etc.
}
```

This seems to work fine, and generates the following table.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[RailcarTrips](
    [WaybillRailcarId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [StartDate] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL,
    [DeliveryDate] [datetime2](7) NULL,
    [ReleaseDate] [datetime2](7) NULL,
    [ReturnDate] [datetime2](7) NULL,
    [DeliveryEta] [datetime2](7) NULL,
    [ReleaseEta] [datetime2](7) NULL,
    [ReturnEta] [datetime2](7) NULL,
    [ReturnCity] [nvarchar](80) NULL,
    [ReturnState] [nvarchar](2) NULL,
    [TripType] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_RailcarTrips] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [WaybillRailcarId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[RailcarTrips]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_RailcarTrips_WaybillRailcars_WaybillRailcarId] FOREIGN KEY([WaybillRailcarId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[WaybillRailcars] ([Id])
ON DELETE CASCADE
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[RailcarTrips] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_RailcarTrips_WaybillRailcars_WaybillRailcarId]
GO
```

But I get an error when I try to change this PK/FK so that it references a different record.

> The property 'RailcarTrip.WaybillRailcarId' is part of a key and so cannot be modified or marked as modified. To change the principal of an existing entity with an identifying foreign key, first delete the dependent and invoke 'SaveChanges', and then associate the dependent with the new principal.

I don't understand why this is a problem? The primary key is not set as an entity/autoset. This code should be a simple update of a FK. I don't want to have to delete anything. Can anyone explain why it's an issue?

This appears to be an Entity Framework error and not a SQL Server error.

Comment: Why you just don't add an autoincrement primary key and forget about this. Otherwise you will one problem after another during the whole project development .

Comment: @Serge: Because, as a PK/FK, I need to be able to set this PK to a specific row ID. Entity Framework will automatically make PKs autoincrement. But it correctly doesn't do that here.

Comment: That would make it cheaper to change the FK, and enable EF to support the operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EF doesn't support modifying primary keys.  So you need to delete and insert (Remove+SaveChanges+Add+SaveChanges) the RailCarTrip to move it to a different WaybillRailcar.  Alternatively you can update the PK/FK directly in TSQL.

Comment: it can be done by stored procedure as well

Comment: Thanks, seems like sending raw SQL commands is the most performant answer. I don't understand why EF blocks this. And I could need to do this for any number of records at a time.

Comment: After careful consideration, I can see why this might not be the best approach. Perhaps I will rework it so that I have a separate PK and FK, and just put a unique index on the FK.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood You correctly, that is that you want to change the value of primary key of your entity (`RailcarTrip`), than You have answered Your own question - EF is informing you, that primary key is not a modifiable value, which is correct for SQL database.
It does not matter if this key is also a foreign key.
To modify a primary key value one has to delete corresponding entry and recreate it with new key value.

Comment: SQL Server (and Azure SQL Database) support updating primary keys, it's just rarely a good idea.

Comment: As @DavidBrowne-Microsoft indicates, it is allowed. I don't know why it would not be a good idea. It certainly seems to be a good idea here. Either way, I don't understand why EF doesn't allow it.

Comment: Entities are tracked by PK, so it would complicate change tracking.  Not an intractable problem in theory, but EF just hasn’t implemented it.